# Python regex expression, what does +X mean?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly this regex pattern is searching for mostly due to the number at the end. From what I can tell, it is saying search for any character that is not a-z and repeat it for the whole string. What does the 3 do?

```
   [^a-z.+3]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `3` is just a literal. It matches char "3".

Comment: It's really only half a question. Beyond the simple technical details of what a character class is, without seeing how it's used, it's really only _half a question_. If you re-label the question I'd up-vote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a character class all characters loose their special meaning (if any), only the first `^` is used to negate the class, `-` is used to define a range *(except at the first and last position)*, an eventual backslash may start an escape sequence and `]` closes the class.

`3` is the literal character `3`, `+` is the literal character `+`, `.` is a literal `.`, nothing more.

`[^a-z.+3]` matches one character that isn't in this list and is the same as `[^.a-z3+]` or `[^+.a-z3]`

Answer (score 2):

`[^a-z.+3]`  match characters other than `a-z` `.` `+` and `3`

lets take an example,

```
x = 'stack overflow... 363 is amazing++useful'
```

lets take each element in regex one by one.

`[^a-z]` matches characters other than `a-z`

```
In [19]: re.findall(r'[^a-z]', x)
Out[19]: [' ', '.', '.', '.', ' ', '3', '6', '3', ' ', ' ', '+', '+']
```

`[^a-z.]` matches characters other than `a-z` and `.`

```
In [20]: re.findall(r'[^a-z.]', x)
Out[20]: [' ', ' ', '3', '6', '3', ' ', ' ', '+', '+']
```

`[^a-z.+]` matches characters other than `a-z` `.` `+`

```
In [21]: re.findall(r'[^a-z.+]', x)
Out[21]: [' ', ' ', '3', '6', '3', ' ', ' ']
```

`[^a-z.+3]` matches characters other than `a-z` `.` `+` `3`

```
In [22]: re.findall(r'[^a-z.+3]', x)
Out[22]: [' ', ' ', '6', ' ', ' ']
```

Answer (score 1):

It searches anything `not in lowercase a-z, dot, plus sign and number 3`
Try [here](http://regexr.com/). Paste in your regex pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
[^a-z.+3]
```

`[^a-z.+3]` match a single character not present in the list below

`a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)

`.+3` a single character in the list .+3 literally

from  : https://regex101.com/r/wI5hG2/1

So in one line this match a caracter different of `a to z` and `.` and `+` and `3`